# Running DC motor at higher than spec voltage, but less current than max

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a LS-280SF-20508 6V DC motor that I am hoping to re-purpose for a project, but I would like to use a 12V power supply as I have had better luck with MOSFET switching using standard (rather than Logic) FETs.

- The motor will be running ~15 sec at a time, and at-most twice per day.
- I will be using a 12V, 0.5A power supply (6 Watt max)
- The spec sheet says that this motor supply can consume 2.6A (I assume at 6V) under peak efficiency -> meaning max 15.6 Watt.

Given this information, can I assume that I probably won't burn out this motor under these conditions? Am I also safe to assume that I won't burn my house down?

Comment: You can almost always get away with this, provided you limit the average power to what it’s rated for.

Comment: To lower the current, gear the motor down. You can't reduce current by just using a lower current supply, it will probably just shut down when you try to start the motor. (A degree of over-voltage is OK . 2x will shorten the life of the brushes a bit, but in this application is probably OK)

Answer (score 1):

Your aversion to MOSFETs that work on 6 V or less gate drive is silly.  The simplest answer is therefore to use a 6 V supply with sufficient current rating to fully run the motor.  You are then running the motor in spec, so there should be no problem.

For completeness, if you only had a 12 V supply for some reason, there are some options:

Just do it.  Since you are only running the motor for 15 seconds at a time with long rests to cool off, it will probably not get hot enough to suffer damage.  This will be especially true if the motor can rotate nicely.  That will cause it to develop back EMF, which effectively subtracts from its supply voltage.  The motor will actually draw less current at 12 V when turning fast enough than at 6 V when stalled.  It's the current that matters to heat dissipation.

PWM with 50% duty cycle.  Use a fast enough PWM frequency so that the current changes little during one pulse.  Since you can use "dumb" 50% fixed PWM, there should be no problem running it at 50-100 kHz.  That's still plenty slow enough to avoid most switching losses.  Make sure to put a Schottky diode in reverse across the motor.  That will keep the switch from getting fried, and give the current a path to keep circulating during the off phase of each PWM pulse.

Your 12 V supply is inapprorpriate because it can't provide enough current.  When the motor starts, it will try to draw a lot of current.  The supply voltage will collapse, or the supply will temporarily shut down.  Either way, the motor won't get going.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need 12V with MOSFETs or do you have a certain driver IC already selected?

Your first problem will be to lower the current. Which means you have to use a series resistor because you don't want to lower the voltage. If you selected MOSFETs for their lower resistance: you just lost that ten fold!

Secondly: torque (mechanical output power) is linear with current. 0.5A means you have about five times less torque then with 2.6A.

Comment: Using a series resistor will not reduce the current it will reduce the voltage and speed. If reducing the speed reduces the torque required to turn the load, that will reduce the current.

Comment: @CharlesCowie User wants max 0.5A. My calculation: 6V motor draws ~2.6A. Resistive equivalence is 6V/2.6A ~2.3Ohms. As user wants max 0.5A at 12V (power supply limit) Thus we need total resistance of 24 Ohm. Therefore need about 22Ohm series resistor to reduce total current. It is not accurate because if motor runs slower back-EMF will be lower but 22Ohm will be about required and will determine current for 90%. Please point out where I am wrong.

Comment: The resistance of the motor is negligible. The back EMF of the motor is what determines the current. Look at the equivalent circuit for a DC motor and the torque vs. speed curve.